# Gödel numbering negations

Tags: logic, incompleteness

I am trying to teach myself Gödel numbering from this SEP page: https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/goedel-incompleteness/sup1.html

I understand why the Gödel number of '0=0' is 2430 (in this coding system), but further on the article talks about negation: neg(⌈A⌉)=(⌈¬A⌉)

What is the Gödel number of ⌈¬A⌉? And why?

Comment: It is $2^9 \times 3^{\ulcorner A \urcorner}$.

Comment: The important thing about Gödel numbering is that there _is_ a scheme for encoding formulas as numbers and back again, and processing the formulas via their numeric representations.  **The specific details of the scheme are not important**.  In the 1930s when Gödel was writing, the existence of such a scheme was not obvious and he had to explain with a specific and detailed example. In 2017, it _is_ obvious, because we _constantly_ process all sorts of things via numeric representations: photographs, videos, personnel records, books, implementations of algorithms, and, yes¸ logical formulas.

Comment: A modern translation of Gödel's theorem could dispense with all the details of the Gödel numbering, and replace them with something like “We write the formula in Unicode using the following characters: ….  It is now obvious that we can write a computer program that checks to see if its input is a valid proof.”  This would suffice for what Gödel needs to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What is the Gödel number of ⌈¬A⌉? And why?

First of all, where $A$ is a *formula* of logic (i.e a string of symbols), $\lceil A \rceil$ is the Gödel number of that formula.  So notice that there is no such thing as 'the Gödel number of $\lceil \neg A \rceil$'; that's like asking what is the Gödel number of the Gödel number of $\neg A$. The Gödel numbering only applies to formulas (which may be the logical representation of numbers, but which aren't numbers themselves).

Second, the function $neg$ is simply *defined* as the function that maps the Godel number of any formula $A$ to the Godel number of the formula $\neg A$ ... it, by itself, does not tell you how to *figure out* what the Godel number of $\neg A$ is on the basis of the Godel number of $A$.  For that, you simply go back to the idea of numbering strings/sequences of symbols as explained in the article.  Thus, where $A$ is $0=0$, $\neg A$ is $\neg 0 = 0$, and so its Godel number is:

$$2^9 \cdot 3^1 \cdot 5^5 \cdot 7^1 = 33600000$$

Finally - and this has nothing to do with your question - the article seems to have a slight problem in that it defines $impl(\lceil A \rceil, \lceil B \rceil) = \lceil A \rightarrow B \rceil$ .... but that should probably be $impl(\lceil A \rceil, \lceil B \rceil) = \lceil ( A \rightarrow B ) \rceil$, for if you don't put parentheses around the conditional, then $neg(impl(\lceil A \rceil, \lceil B \rceil))$ would give the Godel number of $\neg A \rightarrow B$ instead of the desired $\neg (A \rightarrow B)$ ... you should send Panu an email about this!

Answer (score 2):

The general idea is simple: every "basic" symbol has a code (its own G-number).

A formula (i.e. an expression of the language) is a *finite* string of symbols.

Thus, a formula $abc$ (where $a,b,c$ are basic symbols) is encoded with $c = \ulcorner abc \urcorner = 2^{c_1} \times 3^{c_2} \times 5^{c_3}$, where $c_1 = \ulcorner a \urcorner$ is the code of the symbol $a$, and so on.

Thus, the code of $\lnot A$ is $2^9 \times 3^{\ulcorner A \urcorner}$.

For example, the G-number of $¬(0=0)$ will be : $2^9 \times 3^{2430}$.